# Why Android Studio's Emulator is Not Downloading?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

when I started to install android studio completely I stacked when emulator file is not downloading. I tried for 2nd time but failed. All other files are downloaded already. I got a error like this...

**java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Read timed out.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1YzR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check internet connection. Maybe you need to VPN. Maybe you haven't enough space in your PC. Try another emulator.